# Error reading character of string - Access violation error C++

Tags: c++, pointers, kinect

I working with a Kinect v2 related project in C++ while I cannot use Depth Frame (BYTE*) outside the function.

It works for first some minutes I think by luck so.

Then I got errors like:

> Error reading characters of string

and Access violation error and no symbols loaded for kinect20.dll at some point of time.

Here is the method I am calling the values.

```
BYTE* bodyIndex = new BYTE[512*424]; // initialization



HRESULT frameGet(){
//Initialization method if success
    hr = pDepthFrame->AccessUnderlyingBuffer(&m_nDepthBufferSize, &bodyIndex); //Kinect dll method
    prints(depth[300]); // Prints the value every time
    return hr;
}

HRESULT getDepthFrame(){
   if frameGet is success
   prints(bodyIndex[300]); // throws error reading character of string
   return hr; 
}
```

Can anyone please explain how I can access the bodyIndex data everytime.

I didnt get any response when posted the full code so need the logic how c++ works.

If assumption is right the depth data got cleaned up after sometimes by kinectdll so it reflects.

I tried with memcpy the error still there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `depth` a global variable as declared in the code above?

Comment: You might need to evaluate the call `pDepthFrame->AccessUnderlyingBuffer(&m_nDepthBufferSize, &depth);` w.r.t [1] Whether the buffer pointer by `depth` is having any relation to size `m_nDepthBufferSize`. Also are you accessing the buffer well with limits as specified by `m_nDepthBufferSize`. [2] Does the function `AccessUnderlyingBuffer` fills the buffer pointer by `depth` and also return the size of data copied in buffer by storing size in `m_nDepthBufferSize`. [3] Is depth internally allocated by `AccessUnderlyingBuffer` in which case you will receive allocation size in `m_nDepthBufferSize`

Comment: @CinCout yes depth is defined as global ..

Comment: @sameerkn 1st one is exactly working. Once all the data verified, it fills the data according to m_nDepthBufferSize. In that  case in the first function it prints the depth value then while I trying to get by the same depth value it showing the above errors.

Comment: @Vivek: Which means after the call to `AccessUnderlyingBuffer`, `depth` points to buffer which is internally allocated of size `m_nDepthBufferSize`. Try this:  `frameGet(){BYTE *depth = NULL; m_nDepthBufferSize = 0; hr = pDepthFrame->AccessUnderlyingBuffer(&m_nDepthBufferSize, &depth); g_Buffer = new BYTE[m_nDepthBufferSize]; memcpy(g_Buffer, depth, m_nDepthBufferSize);}` Make `BYTE *g_Buffer=NULL;` a global variable. Now you can access data via `g_Buffer`

Comment: @sameerkn working like a charm .. 
But memcpy only copies the memory I hope. If the original value erased then it will affect too. 
Fox ex : int main()
{
 int i[] = { 1,2,3 };
 int *pi = i; 
 cout << pi[1];
 int *pii = NULL; 
 memcpy(&pii, &pi, sizeof(int) * 3);
 delete i;
 cout << endl << pii[1];
 getchar();
    return 0;
}

Comment: @sameerkn Can you please post in answer section ..

Comment: @Vivek: There are 2 mistakes in you previous comment. [1] You did not allocate memory for `pii`. [2] Also you are deleting a static array `i`.  However, `memcpy` will copy actual bytes from source to destination buffer. So it doesn't matter even if source buffer gets destroyed. You can always access the data in destination buffer with the restriction that you need to periodically keep coping new data into it if required.

Comment: @sameerkn Thanks a lot .. you saved my day .. 
You answer should be accepted for future use .. Please post in answer section :)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.kinect.idepthframe.accessunderlyingbuffer.aspx

you don't need to allocate the memory.

> Gets a pointer to the depth frame data.
>
> ```
> public:
> HRESULT AccessUnderlyingBuffer(
>          UINT *capacity,
>          UINT16 **buffer
> )
> ```
>
> buffer Type: UINT16 [out] When this method returns, contains the
>   pointer to the depth frame data.

If I understand the spec correctly you have always call `AccessUnderlyingBuffer()` before access to it.

Comment: Yes but what i need is BodyIndexFrame .. I named that as depth .. my mistake .. 
For that the Byte* is not accessible.